# why am I getiing 0 as a result,I want the return value as the result?

Tags: c++, function, return, return-value

I want the result to be the returned value from the mystery function,but the result is always 0 .but I want the program to return a value that's collected from the mystery function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Mystery(int n)
{
    //  int k;
    if (n <= 1)
    {

        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int k = n;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            k = k + 5;
        }
        cout << ((k * (n / 2)) + (8 * (n / 4)));
        cout << "\n ";
        return ((k * Mystery(n / 2)) + (8 * Mystery(n / 4)));
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, n;

    cout << "Enter n:"; //array size
    cin >> n;

    int result = Mystery(n);
    cout << "The result is " << result;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's desk check what happens when you call `Mystery(2)`.  The final return value is:

```
((k* Mystery(n/2)) + (8* Mystery(n/4)))
```

We know that `n == 2` so let's substitute that:

```
((k* Mystery(1)) + (8* Mystery(0 /* by integer division of 2/4 */)))
```

This will call the function recursively twice with the respective arguments `1` and `0`.  But we know that the terminating case `n <= 1` returns 0, so we can substitute that:

```
((k* 0) + (8* 0))
```

Anything multiplied by zero is zero, so this reduces to `0 + 0` which is also zero. It doesn't even matter what `k` is.

Quite simply, the terminating case for this recursion mandates that the result is always zero.

- In the terminating case the return value is zero.
- In the recursive case, the recursive call result is multiplied with another value to produce the return value.
- Therefore, the result is always going to be zero for any `n`.

I'm not sure exactly how this function is *supposed* to work as you have not explained that, but changing the terminating case to `return 1;` may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't expect which result you want, but I think you can get write result when you correct conditions like

```
if (n == 0)
  return 0;
if (n == 1)
  return 1;
```

I hope it returns the right result.